# How to access qt directories in .pro file?

Tags: qt, qmake

I want to build qt application that will gather all the necessary binaries for standalone execution on install.

I know that can be done in lines of:

```
QT_DIR=C:/Qt/4.8.4
dlls_to_move.files += $$DIR/bin/QtCore.dll
```

however that seems clumsy. Is there a way to retrieve Qt binary folder actually used, like project directory that can be retrieved with $$PWD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [qmake Advanced Usage](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qmake-advanced-usage.html):

> The special $$[...] operator can be used to access various configuration options that were set when Qt was built:

So I think you'd want to do this in your project file:

> dlls_to_move.files += $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]/QtCore.dll